# Celestron Astromaster EQ130

Tags: the-moon, telescope

I recently purchased a Celestron Astromaster EQ130 telescope and have absolutely no clue about telescopes but would love to learn.
I have set this up but cannot even get a decent view of the moon, any advice of help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about your problem.  Can you see the moon at all, and if so what does it look like.  Have you looked at terrestrial objects, such as distant buildings or landscapes?

Comment: Why can't you get a decent view of the Moon? Have you tried doing terrestrial viewing to see if the optical system is working correctly? Did you assemble the telescope correctly? Does the primary mirror look clean? Did you collimate it? Have you tried adjusting the focuser?

Comment: Agree with the above comments - try using it in the day pointing out to trees in the distance and try focusing.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever difficulty you're having, the surest way to get past it is probably an in-person tutorial with an experienced telescope user.
Find a local astronomy club via
the [Astronomical League](https://www.astroleague.org/societies),
the [NASA Night Sky Network](https://nightsky.jpl.nasa.gov/clubs-and-events.cfm),
[Sky and Telescope](https://www.skyandtelescope.com/clubs-organizations/),
or [Go Astronomy](http://www.go-astronomy.com/astronomy-orgs.htm).
Then bring your scope to a public observing session, and most likely someone there will be willing and able to help.